# Remove an item from a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I delete an item from a list in Haskell?
I've got this code but it doesn't seems to work. The concept its, I've got 2 lists, the aList will always have just one element. bList will always have the element that its in aList. So I want to delete the element from bList and at the end, output the new list without that item. Could give some hints please?
Thanks

```
removeFromList :: aList -> bList -> finalList
removeFromList [] _           = []
removeFromList (y:ys) (x:xs)
                  | y == x = removeFromDatabase y xs
                  | otherwise = y : removeFromDatabase y xs
```

Comment: `remove xs ys = [y | y <- ys, not (y 'elem' xs)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
removeFromList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
removeFromList _ []           = []
removeFromList (y:ys) (x:xs)
                  | y == x = removeFromList [y] xs
                  | otherwise = x : removeFromList [y] xs
```

There are a few issues:

The first list should contain the element but you appear to be getting it from the second in the first clause, so it should be:

```
removeFromList _ [] = []
```

Secondly, you need to recreate the list containing the single element when making the recursive calls i.e. `removeFromList [y] xs`

Thirdly the list types should be the same, and you need the `Eq` constraint for `==`

Comment: You could use `ys@(y:_)`; `removeFromList ys` instead of building a new list each time.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you *always* have a single element in `aList`, I'd propose another solution:

```
removeFromList :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
removeFromList [elem] = filter (== elem)
```

Or, if you have only one occurence of that element:

```
import Data.List
removeFromList [elem] = delete elem
```

But remember, it will fail if the first argument somehow appears to be empty or have more than one element.

Problems in your code:

- You use `aList` and `bList` not as argument names, but as type variables in the function signature, which are too general (equivalent to `removeFromList :: a -> b -> c`)
- When you recursively call the function, you pass `y` which is a single element, not a list.

Comment: Aaaaand I can scrap by draft. Again. +1, although I would propose to drop the list around the argument (`rfl :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]`), for the reasons you already gave.

Comment: I agree, but the questioner required the first argument to be a list — maybe this function is already used somewhere. Or probably they had the wrong declaration from the very beginning :)