# how would I go about deleting something from a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to make a function that given the name of a person deletes all entries in the phone book with that name.

```
 type Name = String
 type PhoneNumber = Int
 type Person  = (Name, PhoneNumber)
type PhoneBook = [Person]
delete::Name -> PhoneBook -> PhoneBook
```

how would go about this
would I use drop 
I've been using this but I've been getting error

```
  delete  :: Name -> PhoneBook -> PhoneBook
 delete name = (drop name xs)
```

Comment: Take a look at [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:filter)

Comment: What is the error message? Did you read and try to understand it? What specifically is confusing you about it? Something that will be useful to you is to open ghcid and learn to load a file and ask the types of things with `:t`, e.g. what is the type of `drop`? What are the types of the arguments you're trying to pass it above? Also please be careful how you enter code in SO questions. It's not clear whether you've just done a sloppy paste job or whether your actual code has screwed up indentation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove an item from a list in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073890/remove-an-item-from-a-list-in-haskell)

Comment: You might be better off looking at `Data.Map` and its `Map` data structure. As well as being more efficient than a list of pairs, it has many convenience functions - including `delete` which does exactly what you're looking for. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.0.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

First of all, if you're trying to delete one specific element from a list in Haskell you're usually doing something wrong. There are better types to do this, from`Data.Map` in this case to `Data.Ord` in many others.

However, if you want to do it your way, `drop` is not the function for it. If you look at its type, `drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]` you'll realise it only drops the first n elements.

## Solution

You can however use a higher order function, `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` which does what it says on the tin. Just need to give it a function to filter what you need. You can use a lambda function with an easy pattern matching:

```
deletePerson :: Name -> [PhoneBook] -> [PhoneBook]
deletePerson na = filter (\(n, p) -> name /= n)
```

Also note that `delete` is a function in `Data.List` that deletes the first occurrence of something in a list